# I have extended a AbstractUser model. But I'm not able to login with username & password

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, oauth-2.0, django-views

I am creating an API for signup. Based on signup username & password I need to perform login. But it say user not found. After logging in it should pass the OAuth2 token & other user details.

Model.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    """This Class is used to extend the in-build user model """
    ROLE_CHOICES = (('CREATOR','CREATOR'),('MODERATOR','MODERATOR'),('USERS','USERS'))
    GENDER_CHOICES = (('MALE','MALE'),('FEMALE',"FEMALE"),('OTHER','OTHER'))
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(max_length=10, verbose_name='Date of Birth', null=True)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', verbose_name='Profile Image', default='images/default.webp', blank=True)
    bio = models.TextField(verbose_name='Bio')
    role = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='Role', choices=ROLE_CHOICES)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, verbose_name='Gender', choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
```

serializers.py

```
class LoginSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=25)
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=25)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','password')

    def validate(self, **kwargs):
        username = self.validated_data.get("username", None)
        password = self.validated_data.get("password", None)
        print(username)
        print(password)
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        print(user)
        if user is None:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('User Not Found')
        else:
            return Response({'username':'ronaldo'})
```

views.py

```
class UserLoginAPI(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        response = {
            'success':'True',
            'status_code':status.HTTP_200_OK,
            'message':'Login Successfully',
        }
        status_code = status.HTTP_200_OK
        return Response(response, status=status_code)
```

I think i'm doing it in wrong way. As i'm using OAuth2 toolkit to generate token. So please help

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback

Comment: That's the entire traceback

Comment: Nope, it is the last line of the traceback which is the type of error and its detail. We have to know which part of the code is throwing the exception. Your traceback starts from the line it says <the following exception occurred blah blah> Also, if you are using OAuth2 toolkit I don't think you need an actual login serializer, like [see here](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rest-framework/getting_started.html#step-3-register-an-application)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, use the create method instead of post in viewset and call self.perform_create(serializer) to call the 'create' method in the serializer.

```
class UserLoginAPI(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        response = {
        'success':'True',
        'status_code':status.HTTP_200_OK,
        'message':'Login Successfully',
         }
         status_code = status.HTTP_200_OK
        return Response(response, status=status_code)


class LoginSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=25)
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=25)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','password')

   def validate(self, **kwargs):
       # some validation ( null check)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        username = self.validated_data.get("username", None)
        password = self.validated_data.get("password", None)
        print(username)
        print(password)
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        print(user)
        if user is None:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('User Not Found')
        return user
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, will I be able to get the OAuth2 token after entering login credentials